# Rails: Using Devise with single table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, single-table-inheritance

I am having a problem getting [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) to work the way I'd like with single table inheritance.

I have two different types of account organised as follows:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable
end

class User < Account
end

class Company < Account
end
```

I have the following routes:

```
devise_for :account, :user, :company
```

Users register at `/user/sign_up` and companies register at `/company/sign_up`. All users log in using a single form at `/account/sign_in` (`Account` is the parent class).

However, logging in via this form only seems to authenticate them for the `Account` scope. Subsequent requests to actions such as `/user/edit` or `/company/edit` direct the user to the login screen for the corresponding scope.

How can I get Devise to recognise the account 'type' and authenticate them for the relevant scope?

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just ran into the exact scenario (with class names changed) as outlined in the question.  Here's my solution (Devise 2.2.3, Rails 3.2.13):

in config/routes.rb:

```
devise_for :accounts, :controllers => { :sessions => 'sessions' }, :skip => :registrations
devise_for :users, :companies, :skip => :sessions
```

in app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    def create
        rtn = super
        sign_in(resource.type.underscore, resource.type.constantize.send(:find, resource.id)) unless resource.type.nil?
        rtn
    end
end
```

Note: since your Accounts class will still be :registerable the default links in views/devise/shared/_links.erb will try to be emitted, but new_registration_path(Accounts) won't work (we :skip it in the route drawing) and cause an error.  You'll have to generate the devise views and manually remove it.

Hat-tip to https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/plataformatec-devise/s4Gg3BjhG0E for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I used this and I get the error NoMethodError (undefined method 'type' ... On the line sign_in(resource.type ... What do I need to do to change this?

Comment: I'm guessing just make a string column in account named type? And set it to the model name?

Comment: That would be my guess as well.  ActiveRecord STI expects that.

Comment: I tried this, and my app is still crashing on the new_registration_path issue mentioned in the note. Since all the Devise views use generic resource paths, how do I manually remove the new_registration_path(Accounts)?

Answer (score 16):

There is an easy way to handle STI in the routes.

Let's say you have the following STI models:

```
def Account < ActiveRecord::Base
# put the devise stuff here
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end

def User < Account
end

def Company < Account
```

A method that is often overlooked is that you can specify a block in the authenticated method in your routes.rb file:

```
## config/routes.rb

devise_for :accounts, :skip => :registrations
devise_for :users, :companies, :skip => :sessions

# routes for all users
authenticated :account do
end

# routes only for users
authenticated :user, lambda {|u| u.type == "User"} do
end

# routes only for companies
authenticated :user, lambda {|u| u.type == "Company"} do
end
```

To get the various helper methods like "current_user" and "authenticate_user!" ("current_account" and "authenticate_account!" are already defined) without having to define a separate method for each (which quickly becomes unmaintainable as more user types are added), you can define dynamic helper methods in your ApplicationController:

```
## controllers/application_controller.rb
def ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  %w(User Company).each do |k| 
    define_method "current_#{k.underscore}" do 
        current_account if current_account.is_a?(k.constantize)
    end 

    define_method "authenticate_#{k.underscore}!" do 
    |opts={}| send("current_#{k.underscore}") || not_authorized 
    end 
  end
end
```

This is how I solved the rails devise STI problem.

Comment: Should not :user be :company in this line of code ?                                      ``` # routes only for companies
authenticated :user, lambda {|u| u.type == "Company"} do
end ```

Answer (score 1):

try to change routes like so:
**devise_for :accounts, :users, :companies**
because Devise uses plural names for it's resources

Please let me know if it help you

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, this didn't solve the problem. Logging in via `/accounts/sign_in` still doesn't allow me to access `/users/edit` or `/companies/edit`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible without overriding the sessions controller.  Each sign_in page has a specific scope that devise will authenticate against as defined by your routes.

It may be possible to use the same sign_in page for multiple user scopes by using the devise_scope function in your routes file to force both :users and :companies to use the same sign in page (a how-to can be found [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes)), but I'm pretty certain that you would have to modify your sessions controller to do some custom logic in order to determine which type of user is signing in.

Comment: @gjb How were you able to handle this? Have you found a better solution?