# Rails Devise - multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I need help with devise and the option to use multiple models.

At the moment i got a *User* model and a *Client* model which is inside a namespace:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :registerable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end

class Test::Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

As you can see, i included devise in both models. Like its in the doc..

So have a look at my *routes*:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {passwords: 'passwords',
                               sessions: 'sessions'}

devise_for :clients, class_name: 'Test::Client', controllers: {sessions: 'test/sessions'}
```

My problem now is, that when i create a login form for my *Client* model:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: client_session_path(resource_name), html: {class: ''}) do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

it has following url: **/clients/sign_in.client**

What is this **.client**? It drives me crazy. When you need more informations let me know..

**EDIT 1:**

I edited my model structure now.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :registerable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end

class Test::Client < User
    # some Client only functions
end
```

So the login as a normal User works. But the Client login still doesn't. In my view i did this:

```
<%= form_for(Test::Client.new, as: :client, url: session_path(:client)
```

When i enter my credentials i get redirected to "/users/sign_in" but nothing else happend. In my log i got a filter entry:

```
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
```

Comment: why not STI ? `class Test::Client < User`

Comment: @huanson i already tried this. But then i got the problem that the object is always type *User* but i need *Client* methods and so on

Comment: ya well, u still have the user and the test::client and the client you can extend everything. but still just one login and 1 routing

Comment: i know what you mean. But when i login with some data, i get an user object. And i cant go form user object to client object. U understand what i mean?

Comment: of course you can go! just override the current_user method and if its type=Client, then it returns a test::client object.

Comment: @huanson i dont get it. So i must add a type column to the user table?

Comment: just google a little for STI (single table inheritance) then you can see what i mean

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690406/rails-using-devise-with-single-table-inheritance

Comment: this looks good http://funonrails.com/2011/12/multiple-resources-registrations-with/

Comment: @huanson Ok. I implemented it as the example says. But look at my edit to see what happend when i try to login.

Comment: so now everything is good?

Comment: @huanson yes. Everythings fine now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to the original question
in my app

```
<%= user_session_path(resource_name) %>
# Output
/users/sign_in.user
# In this example; the `resource_name` is redundant

<%= user_session_path %> 
# no need to pass arg is your are surely gonna use `user` as the resource
# Output
/users/sign_in

<%= session_path(:user) %>
# Output
/users/sign_in
```

there is a helper method defined in devise to determine the sign_in_url according to resource;

> What is this .client?
>   Ans: `client` is the name of the resource you defined for `devise`; in your case there are two resources;

use the following if you are gonna have different view templates for different resources;

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: client_session_path, html: {class: ''}) do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

If want to share the view template; use

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), html: {class: ''}) do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

FYI :

```
[8] pry(main)> app.members_path
=> "/members"
[9] pry(main)> app.leads_path(2)
=> "/leads.2"
[10] pry(main)> app.lead_path(2)
=> "/leads/2"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can login now but i cant access the user. Current_user is empty. When i try to login the message "youre already logged in" appears.

Comment: how come; if you are logged in there must be `current_user` set; could your share the error log please

Comment: Oh; since you are using the `client` resource so; no `current_user` is set; try `current_client`

Comment: Damn man youre a genius <3 I work like 2 days on this sh*t. Thanks!

Comment: dude; we are here to help people :) making this world a better place